# How can make it select the exact word that is typed in uib-typehead(bootstrap)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Am using **uib-typehead** from **bootstrap** in angularjs in html,

http://plnkr.co/edit/4vVznXyjZo3HuIb2p5as?p=preview

```
<div class="form-group"> {{customer}}
  <input placeholder="Vælg kunde" type="text" ng-model="customer" typeahead-editable="true" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" typeahead-min-length="0" typeahead-no-results="noResults">

   <span ng-if="noResults" uib-dropdown uib-dropdown-toggle auto-close="disabled" is-open="true">
      <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" >
        <li><a href>no results</a></li>
      </ul>
    </span>

</div>
```

Here my question is how can add my own value('Cal' string) that is not in array(here 'states' array).

For example, on the below link, on the input box, if i type 'Cal', then, the 'California' will be selected if i press enter, **but, instead of this**, if i type 'Cal', then, 'Cal' only should be selected if i press enter.

How Can i make this changes? Any help please?